# Arduino weird bluetooth module

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

Recently I bought a BT module from eBay which was very cheap. I didn't really noticed the image and I just bought it. When it came I couldn't find any holes to solder the headers. Also the specific module is pretty rare and I couldn't find anything.

Here is an image:

[image: BlueTooth Module]

How do I wire up this chip?

Comment: Are you able to post a clearer photo? If your camera has a close-up or 'macro' mode then it may help.

Comment: You at least post a link to the item on ebay; the blur pict you linked to is totally useless currently.

Comment: @jfpoilpret Not exactly useless, but it definitely needs improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the picture you posted, i was able to google and find something called a BC04-B Bluetooth serial module. It looks almost exactly like yours, and I found a diagram on how to hook it up.
[image: BC04-B Bluetooth serial module]

I also believe that these are the serial commands you can use with it...
[image: Bluetooth module serial commands]

Comment: It could be HC-06 or HC-05 but they operate quite similarly.

Answer (score 2):

These Bluetooth modules are typically mounted onto another substrate, either the product board or a small PCB backplane which provides the pinouts and any additional circuitry like the pairing LED, and power- & signal-level management.
They are readily available as HC-05 (master/slave) or HC-06 (slave only) with signals brought to through-holes or pins at the edge of the backplane.